# How to set a property on Vue js router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a property defined in my router.map called

```
'/usersFeeds':{
      component: function(resolve){
        require([commonSections + 'usersFeeds.vue'], resolve);
      },
      auth: true,
      user: ''
    },
```

I want to be able to set the "user" property when I call:

```
router.go({ 
   path : 'path',
   user: 'userName'
})
```

Comment: you don't. Route object properties are not meant to be dynamically set. You either pass them as parts of the URL (as properties of `params:` or `query:`), or you use the store pattern store that information in a store object.

Comment: @LinusBorg  I tried passing my property as a 'params' but that didnt show up in the params when i switched to the new route

Comment: you can't set any arbitrary params, only those that are part of the path, for example a path like `/usersfeeds/:user` allows you to pass a param called `user`. But `query:`can contain anything pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send props programatically from a component to router path

```
'/usersFeeds':{
      component: function(resolve){
        require([commonSections + 'usersFeeds.vue'], resolve);
      },
      auth: true,
      user: '',
      props: true
    },

router.push({ 
   path : 'path',
   params: { user: 'userName' }
})
```

The params user is passed as props to the component where it is redirected